# Destroying chart.js is not working when chart created inside function - chart.destroy() is not a function

Tags: javascript, charts, html5-canvas, chart.js

I am using a function to create a chart which uses chart.js.
Unfortunately, whenever I am trying to call chart.destroy() I get the error:

"chart.destroy() is not a function".
My code looks as following:

```
  var chart = {};
  createChart(x_axis_data, y_axis_data, chart); //Function creating chart
```

The chart itself is created inside the function with following:

```
chart = new Chart(document.getElementById(id),{....
```

The chart is created successfully. However, I cannot delte the chart by calling: chart.destroy.
I have already tried to use

```
window.chart.destroy()
```

without any success.

Comment: Well make the variable that holds the chart global instead of local to some function. If you're using jQuery, you can use `.data("chart")` on the target `<canvas>` element to get an existing Chart instance (if any).

Comment: Shouldn´t be my variable already be global? I create it before calling my function and pass it to my function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `window.chart =` rather than relying on the implicit function of `chart =`. If you were using strict mode with your code, it should throw a warning.

Comment: I kind of still get the error: window.chart.destroy is not a function

Comment: I found my mistake. I forgot to use: window.chart inside my function

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/1007

Change:

var myNewChart1 = new Chart(ctx1).Line(barChartData1, {animation: false});

To:

window.myNewChart1 = new Chart(ctx1).Line(barChartData1, {animation: false});

Answer (score 0):

for me using jQuery, I just did $("#container").html="";

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).